# Non CRUD Rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I built the following controller and routes. I'm expecting the form to post to the path, such as `/production/:date`, but I get this instead

```
http://localhost:3000/production/update_week?utf8=✓&date=2015-02-17&commit=Update
```

Controller

```
def index
    @date = session[:week] ||= Date.current
  end

  def show
    @date = params[:date]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  
    end
  end

  def update_week
    session[:week] = params[:date]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to week_path(session[:week]) }
    end
  end
```

Form

```
%p.field
  = form_tag update_week_path, method: :get do
    = label_tag "Week of:"
    = text_field_tag :date, @date, id: 'datepicker'
    = submit_tag "Update"
```

Routes

```
  get 'production/:date' => 'production#show', as: :week
  get 'production' => 'production#index', as: :production
  get 'production/update_week' => 'production#update_week', as: :update_week
```

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/20948/rails-route?tab=general come to this chat room... I will wait for 5 mins

Comment: oh.. maybe you wont have enough reps to join the chat room...what about facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line, you specify the path to be used:

`= form_tag update_week_path, method: :get do`

In your routes, `update_week_path` is this line:

`get 'production/update_week' => 'production#update_week', as: :update_week`

If you want it to go to `production/:date`, you need to use this route:

`get 'production/:date' => 'production#show', as: :week`

Like this:

```
= form_tag week_path(your_date_goes_here), method: :get do
```

Comment: But I don't know the date until the form is changed.

Comment: I still get this url -- `http://localhost:3000/production/2015-02-08?utf8=✓&date=2015-02-17&commit=Update`

Comment: I want a url of `/production/2015-02-22`, not the above.`

Comment: @JesseCrockett If you don't want the query params (after the ?), you need to do a post.